# Camel Azure Event Hub Issue

Tags: apache-camel

My camel route which exposes a rest endpoint and route the message to azure event hub. I am getting encoding error when it is routing the message to event hub. Appreciate if there are any inputs (Route comes online and no connectivity issues )

Here is the code :-

```
@Component
public class RestEventHubRoute extends RouteBuilder {

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        restConfiguration().component("servlet").bindingMode(RestBindingMode.auto);

        from("rest:post:/rest").to(
                "azure-eventhubs://?connectionString=Endpoint=xxx");

    }

}
```

Error :-

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No encoding is known for map entry value of type: org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade
    at org.apache.qpid.proton.codec.MapType.calculateSize(MapType.java:110) ~[proton-j-0.33.8.jar:na]
    at org.apache.qpid.proton.codec.MapType.getEncoding(MapType.java:66) ~[proton-j-0.33.8.jar:na]
    at org.apache.qpid.proton.codec.MapType.getEncoding(MapType.java:29) ~[proton-j-0.33.8.jar:na]
    at org.apache.qpid.proton.codec.AbstractPrimitiveType.write(AbstractPrimitiveType.java:27) ~[proton-j-0.33.8.jar:na]
    at org.apache.qpid.proton.codec.messaging.FastPathApplicationPropertiesType.write(FastPathApplicationPropertiesType.java:173) ~[proton-j-0.33.8.jar:na]
    at org.apache.qpid.proton.codec.messaging.FastPathApplicationPropertiesType.write(FastPathApplicationPropertiesType.java:43) ~[proton-j-0.33.8.jar:na]
    at org.apache.qpid.proton.codec.EncoderImpl.writeObject(EncoderImpl.java:734) ~[proton-j-0.33.8.jar:na]
    at org.apache.qpid.proton.message.impl.MessageImpl.encode(MessageImpl.java:736) ~[proton-j-0.33.8.jar:na]
    at org.apache.qpid.proton.message.impl.MessageImpl.encode(MessageImpl.java:696) ~[proton-j-0.33.8.jar:na]
    at com.azure.messaging.eventhubs.EventDataBatch.getSize(EventDataBatch.java:187) ~[azure-messaging-eventhubs-5.11.2.jar:5.11.2]
    at com.azure.messaging.eventhubs.EventDataBatch.tryAdd(EventDataBatch.java:121) ~[azure-messaging-eventhubs-5.11.2.jar:5.11.2]
    at com.azure.messaging.eventhubs.EventHubProducerAsyncClient$EventDataCollector.lambda$accumulator$0(EventHubProducerAsyncClient.java:698) ~[azure-messaging-eventhubs-5.11.2.jar:5.11.2]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoStreamCollector$StreamCollectorSubscriber.onNext(MonoStreamCollector.java:132) ~[reactor-core-3.4.26.jar:3.4.26]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable$IterableSubscription.fastPath(FluxIterable.java:402) ~[reactor-core-3.4.26.jar:3.4.26]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable$IterableSubscription.request(FluxIterable.java:291) ~[reactor-core-3.4.26.jar:3.4.26]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoStreamCollector$StreamCollectorSubscriber.onSubscribe(MonoStreamCollector.java:121) ~[reactor-core-3.4.26.jar:3.4.26]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable.subscribe(FluxIterable.java:201) ~[reactor-core-3.4.26.jar:3.4.26]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable.subscribe(FluxIterable.java:83) ~[reactor-core-3.4.26.jar:3.4.26]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFromFluxOperator.subscribe(MonoFromFluxOperator.java:81) ~[reactor-core-3.4.26.jar:3.4.26]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:157) ~[reactor-core-3.4.26.jar:3.4.26]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen$ThenIgnoreMain.complete(MonoIgnoreThen.java:292) ~[reactor-core-3.4.26.jar:3.4.26]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen$ThenIgnoreMain.onNext(MonoIgnoreThen.java:187) ~[reactor-core-3.4.26.jar:3.4.26]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen$ThenIgnoreMain.subscribeNext(MonoIgnoreThen.java:236) ~[reactor-core-3.4.26.jar:3.4.26]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen$ThenIgnoreMain.onComplete(MonoIgnoreThen.java:203) ~[reactor-core-3.4.26.jar:3.4.26]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.onComplete(FluxPeek.java:260) ~[reactor-core-3.4.26.jar:3.4.26]
    at reactor.core.publisher.SerializedSubscriber.onComplete(SerializedSubscriber.java:146) ~[reactor-core-3.4.26.jar:3.4.26]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxRetryWhen$RetryWhenMainSubscriber.onComplete(FluxRetryWhen.java:200) ~[reactor-core-3.4.26.jar:3.4.26]
    at reactor.core.publisher.SerializedSubscriber.onComplete(SerializedSubscriber.java:146) ~[reactor-core-3.4.26.jar:3.4.26]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxTimeout$TimeoutMainSubscriber.onComplete(FluxTimeout.java:234) ~[reactor-core-3.4.26.jar:3.4.26]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxTakeUntil$TakeUntilPredicateSubscriber.onComplete(FluxTakeUntil.java:121) ~[reactor-core-3.4.26.jar:3.4.26]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxTakeUntil$TakeUntilPredicateSubscriber.onNext(FluxTakeUntil.java:99) ~[reactor-core-3.4.26.jar:3.4.26]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxReplay$SizeBoundReplayBuffer.replayNormal(FluxReplay.java:877) ~[reactor-core-3.4.26.jar:3.4.26]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxReplay$SizeBoundReplayBuffer.replay(FluxReplay.java:965) ~[reactor-core-3.4.26.jar:3.4.26]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxReplay$ReplaySubscriber.onNext(FluxReplay.java:1344) ~[reactor-core-3.4.26.jar:3.4.26]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.onNext(FluxPeek.java:200) ~[reactor-core-3.4.26.jar:3.4.26]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.onNext(FluxPeek.java:200) ~[reactor-core-3.4.26.jar:3.4.26]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(FluxMap.java:122) ~[reactor-core-3.4.26.jar:3.4.26]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxDistinctUntilChanged$DistinctUntilChangedSubscriber.tryOnNext(FluxDistinctUntilChanged.java:149) ~[reactor-core-3.4.26.jar:3.4.26]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxDistinctUntilChanged$DistinctUntilChangedSubscriber.onNext(FluxDistinctUntilChanged.java:102) ~[reactor-core-3.4.26.jar:3.4.26]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxReplay$SizeBoundReplayBuffer.replayNormal(FluxReplay.java:877) ~[reactor-core-3.4.26.jar:3.4.26]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxReplay$SizeBoundReplayBuffer.replay(FluxReplay.java:965) ~[reactor-core-3.4.26.jar:3.4.26]
    at reactor.core.publisher.ReplayProcessor.tryEmitNext(ReplayProcessor.java:508) ~[reactor-core-3.4.26.jar:3.4.26]
    at reactor.core.publisher.SinkManySerialized.tryEmitNext(SinkManySerialized.java:100) ~[reactor-core-3.4.26.jar:3.4.26]
    at reactor.core.publisher.InternalManySink.emitNext(InternalManySink.java:27) ~[reactor-core-3.4.26.jar:3.4.26]
    at com.azure.core.amqp.implementation.handler.Handler.onNext(Handler.java:89) ~[azure-core-amqp-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
    at com.azure.core.amqp.implementation.handler.SendLinkHandler.onLinkRemoteOpen(SendLinkHandler.java:114) ~[azure-core-amqp-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
    at org.apache.qpid.proton.engine.BaseHandler.handle(BaseHandler.java:164) ~[proton-j-0.33.8.jar:na]
    at org.apache.qpid.proton.engine.impl.EventImpl.dispatch(EventImpl.java:108) ~[proton-j-0.33.8.jar:na]
    at org.apache.qpid.proton.reactor.impl.ReactorImpl.dispatch(ReactorImpl.java:324) ~[proton-j-0.33.8.jar:na]
    at org.apache.qpid.proton.reactor.impl.ReactorImpl.process(ReactorImpl.java:291) ~[proton-j-0.33.8.jar:na]
    at com.azure.core.amqp.implementation.ReactorExecutor.run(ReactorExecutor.java:91) ~[azure-core-amqp-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
    at reactor.core.scheduler.SchedulerTask.call(SchedulerTask.java:68) ~[reactor-core-3.4.26.jar:3.4.26]
    at reactor.core.scheduler.SchedulerTask.call(SchedulerTask.java:28) ~[reactor-core-3.4.26.jar:3.4.26]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:304) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[na:na]
```

I am expecting the route to forward the message to event hub

Answer (score 0):

Maybe too late to help here, but it might help someone else. In my case this was a serialization issue since Eventhubs will try to serialize whatever you send to it. I was able to fix it by removing the Camel headers using:

```
.removeHeaders("*") // Remove all headers
```

Turns out camel sends all headers to the Eventhub too, this can cause problems because the Eventhub will try to serialize these headers too. Removing (some of) them can fix this problem.